# How can I initialize the structure variable that is already being passed?

Tags: c++, io, project

Okay so we have to change this program from reading input from a user to reading it off of a file, and so far i have changed a good chunk of the code that will read off of the file but every time i go to run the code i get these 5 errors that I can't figure out so here is my code

```
// Author:      
// Source file: 
// Description: 
// Compiler used:   

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

struct records
{
    int code;
    double amount;
};
// Function Prototypes
void displayTitle();
double getBegBal(ifstream&);
void displayBal(records);
records getData(ifstream&);
double processCheck(double, double);
double processDeposit(double, double);
double processATM(double, double);
double processSvcChg(double);


//Global Constants
const double    CHARGE = 10,
ATMFEE = 2;

int main()
{
    //Variable Declarations
    int transCode;
    double balance,
        transAmt;


    cout.setf(ios::fixed);
    cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
    cout.precision(2);

    records trans;
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("c:\\checkIn.dat");

    displayTitle();
    balance = getBegBal(inFile);
    getData(inFile);

    while (!inFile.eof())
    {
        trans = getData(inFile);

        switch (trans.code)
        {
        case 1: balance = processCheck(balance, trans.amount); break;
        case 2: balance = processDeposit(balance, trans.amount); break;
        case 3: balance = processATM(balance, trans.amount); break;
        }
        displayBal(trans);
        if (balance < 0)
            balance = processSvcChg(balance);
        getData(inFile);
    }

    return 0;
}


void displayTitle()
{
    cout << "\n       Check Register\n\n";
}

double getBegBal(ifstream& inFile)
{
    //double bal;
    records balance;
    cout << "  Enter beginning balance ";
    inFile >> balance.amount;
    return balance.amount;
}

void displayBal(records balance)
{
    cout << "\t\tBalance = $" << setw(10) << balance.amount;
}

records getData(ifstream& inFile)
{
    records rec;
    cout << "\n\n  Enter transaction code (0 to exit) ";
    inFile >> rec.code;
    if (rec.code > 0)
    {
        cout << "\n  Enter transaction amount ";

    }
    return rec;
}

double processCheck(double bal, double amt)
{
    cout << "\n  Check =    " << setw(10) << amt;
    return (bal - amt);
}

double processDeposit(double bal, double amt)
{
    cout << "\n  Deposit =  " << setw(10) << amt;
    return (bal + amt);
}
double processATM(double bal, double amt)
{
    records trans;

    cout << "\n  ATM     =  " << setw(10) << trans.amount;
    bal = bal - amt;
    displayBal(trans);
    bal = bal - ATMFEE;
    cout << "\n  ATM Fee =  " << setw(10) << ATMFEE;
    return (bal);
}
double processSvcChg(double bal)
{
    records trans;
    cout << "\n  Service chg =" << setw(8) << CHARGE;
    bal = bal - CHARGE;
    displayBal(trans);
    return (bal);
}
```

error #2-3 are here

```
int transCode;
double balance,
    transAmt;
```

the error is saying 'transCode': unreferenced local variable and 
'transAmt': unreferenced local variable

errors #4-5 are here

```
double processATM(double bal, double amt)
{
    records trans;

    cout << "\n  ATM     =  " << setw(10) << trans.amount;
    bal = bal - amt;
    displayBal(trans);// the error points here saying that the variable trans is uninitialized 
    bal = bal - ATMFEE;
    cout << "\n  ATM Fee =  " << setw(10) << ATMFEE;
    return (bal);
}
double processSvcChg(double bal)
{
    records trans;
    cout << "\n  Service chg =" << setw(8) << CHARGE;
    bal = bal - CHARGE;
    displayBal(trans); // the error points here saying that the variable trans is uninitialized
    return (bal);
}
```

Please and thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you please enlighten me why you need to loop on getting the width in your getWidth function?

Comment: `getWidth()` returns the width read, then you throw it away. Catch it!

Comment: This function displays a prompt requesting the value for the width, and returns the
integer value for width. The width must be an odd number so display an error message
to the user if the entry is not an odd number, and request a valid entry. Loop until an
odd number is entered. Do not call this function from main if the menu selection is -9 or
the selection is invalid.

Comment: @DaoXio This function displays a prompt requesting the value for the width, and returns the integer value for width. The width must be an odd number so display an error message to the user if the entry is not an odd number, and request a valid entry. Loop until an odd number is entered. Do not call this function from main if the menu selection is -9 or the selection is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working for me.

```
int displayMenu();
void displaySquare(int width);
void displayTriangle(int width);
int getWidth(); 
void displayUpsideDownTriangle(int width);
void displayDiamond(int width);

int main()
{
    int width, shapes;
    do {

        shapes = displayMenu();
        width = 0;

        switch (shapes)
        {
        case 1: 
            width = getWidth();
            displaySquare(width);
            break;
        case 2: 
            width = getWidth();
            displayTriangle(width);
            break;
        case 3: 
            width = getWidth();
            displayUpsideDownTriangle(width);
            break;
        case 4: 
            width = getWidth();
            displayDiamond(width);
            break;
        case -9: 
            cout << "End of Program " << endl;
        default: 
            cout << "Please choose one of the shapes..." << endl;


        }

    } while (shapes != -9);




    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
//this function sets up the display for the user
int displayMenu() {
    int shapes;
    cout << "\n~~ Shape Display menu ~~ " << endl << endl;
    cout << "     1....Square\n" <<
        "     2....Triangle\n " <<
        "    3....Upside Down triangle\n " <<
        "    4....Diamond\n\n " <<
        "   -9....Exit Program " << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "  Make a selection " << endl;
    cin >> shapes;
    return shapes;

}
int getWidth()
{
    int width = 1;
    do {
        if (width % 2 != 0)
        {
            cout << "Enter width " << endl;
            cin >> width;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Please enter odd number only. \nEnter width " << endl;
            cin >> width;
        }
    } while (width % 2 == 0);

    return width;
}
void displaySquare(int width)
{

    int  rows, columns;


    for (rows = 0; rows < width; ++rows)
    {
        for (columns = 0; columns < width; ++columns)
        {
            cout << "# ";
        }

        cout << endl;
    }

}
void displayTriangle(int width)
{

        int rows, Spacing, ColHashtag;


        for (rows = 1; rows < width; rows++) //controls the rows 
        {
            for (Spacing = (width - rows); Spacing >= 1; Spacing--) // spaces out the rows to make an isoceles triangle
            {
                cout << " ";
            }
            for (ColHashtag = 1; ColHashtag <= (rows * 2) - 1; ColHashtag++) //controls the columns 
            {
                cout << "#";
            }
            cout << endl;

        }


}
void displayUpsideDownTriangle(int width)
{
    int rows, Columns, spacing;

    //sets up the rows for the top 
    for ((rows = width - 1); rows >= 1; rows--)
    {
        for (Columns = 1; Columns <= width - rows; Columns++) // sets up the columns 
        {
            cout << " "; // spaces out the symbols to make an isoceles triangle 
        }
        for (spacing = 1; spacing <= 2 * rows - 1; spacing++)
        {
            cout << "#";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

}
void displayDiamond(int width)
{
    displayTriangle(width);
    displayUpsideDownTriangle(width);
}
```

Comment: Okay now i see what you meant! thank you! It works! :D

Answer (score 2):

You initialized `width = 0;` and passed it to `getWidth()`. Therefore, `width % 2 != 0` is evaluated as false and the prompt in `getWidth()` won't be displayed.

`getWidth()` won't need any arguments unless your assignment requires it because it is intended to just read the width and rethrn it.

`do` statement is useful to evaluate condition after executing loop body once.

```
int getWidth()
{
    int width = 0;
    do {
        cout << "Enter width " << endl;
        cin >> width;
    } while (width % 2 != 0);
    return width;
}
```

Then, use `getWidth()` in `main()` function like this:

```
width = getWidth();
```

Comment: If i did that then i would have to redo all of the functions calling width

Comment: This is the answer. You will only change the getWidth() function. Change the prototype from `int getWidth(int width); ` to `int getWidth(); `

Comment: Okay i tried that and the program didn't even run it gave out these errors

Comment: getWidth: function does not take 1 argument for all four of the shapes

Comment: @BartholomewAllen Do change the usage of `getWidth()` to what I wrote.

Comment: Yes i did @MikeCAT, the previous comment to this shows the error of what happens when i run the code

Comment: @BartholomewAllen [Couldn't reproduce](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/0DnQvNKdwisDmuN4). Are you sure you saved the modified source code and trying to compile it?

Comment: IT works! Sorry i was confused at what you meant but then i saw an example and now the code works great!

Answer (score 0):

replace int main() and getWidth() with this

```
 int main()
{
int width, shapes,wt;  
do {

cout << "Enter width " << endl;
cin >> width; 
    wt=getWidth(width);

    if(wt!=0)
    {
    shapes = displayMenu();
    }
    else
    {
        shapes=-9;
    }
    switch (shapes)
    {
    case 1: 
        displaySquare(wt);
        break;
    case 2: 
        displayTriangle(wt);
        break;
    case 3: 
        displayUpsideDownTriangle(wt);
        break;
    case 4: 
        displayDiamond(wt);
        break;
    case -9: 
        cout << "End of Program " << endl;
        break;
    default: 
        cout << "Please choose one of the shapes..." << endl;


    }

} while (shapes != -9);

system("pause");
return 0;
}

 int getWidth(int width)
{

while (width % 2 != 0) {
    cout << "Enter width " << endl;
    cin >> width;
}
return width; 
}
```